# How do I verify if the API is throwing 200 OK as status code in JMeter

Tags: api, validation, jmeter

So, I recently started learning JMeter and want to create an API validation script for a website called [dummyapi.io](http://dummyapi.io) where I got an app-id. But, I don't understand how to use this in JMeter. What does it mean to use the app-id in the API request header?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter automatically considers [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful so if your app returns status 200 it will be treated as passed.

If you want to add an extra layer of check and verify that particular this request returns 200 response code:

1. Add [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the request you want to validate
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Field to Test: `Response Code`
   - Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
   - Patterns to Test: `200`

     [image]

Similarly you can add additional pass/fail criteria like:

- presence/absence of text in the response body/message/headers/URL
- compare a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) with anticipated value
- check response duration
- check response size
- etc. see [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps) article to learn more about JMeter [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) concept